# How to convert torque in oz-in into the weight it can withstand?

Tags: servomotor, torque

I am looking at servos to make a robot claw, and I want to make sure the one i am getting can turn under a specific amount of weight. The servos specify their torque in oz-in. I am not sure how to read this.

What i need to know is, how to I convert oz-in into the specific weight it can withstand in lbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with the unit of measurement:

1 oz-in = 0.00706 Nm

if you are not familiar with torque:

1 Nm torque translates to 1N of force at a radial distance from the shaft of the motor of 1 m. As 1N gravitational force corresponds to an approx. 0.1kg weight, 1 Nm torque can lift* 0.1kg weight 1m away from the shaft, or 1 kg weight 0.1m away from the shaft.

*Lift in this case means that if such weight is attached to the rotor, the rotor would be in equilibrium, less weight then this would start to rotate.

Comment: So, if i had a length of 2M with 1Nm, would that make 0.5N? @50k4

Comment: exactly, 2m radial distance, 0.5N